# ошибка при оборачивании python проекта в .exe через pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

[image: при оборачивании проекта на python вылетает такая ошибка, может кто с таким встречался и знает как ее решить?]
Пытался разобраться во внутреннем содержании функций, но там совсем не понятно что происходит... в какой-то момент просто строка (как я понял) с названиями функций прогоняется через eval и возвращается в данную функцию, после чего пытается итерироваться как двумерный массив

текст ошибки:
File "c:\app\anaconda\lib\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py",

line 35, in pre_safe_import_module for real_modu1e_name, six_module_name in real_to_six_modu1e_name.items():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute "items"

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, trace ошибки в сам вопрос текстом вместо картинки

Comment: File "c:\app\anaconda\lib\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py", 

line 35, in pre_safe_import_module for real_modu1e_name, six_module_name in real_to_six_modu1e_name.items():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute "items"